# laravel Query Builder return nothing

Tags: php, laravel-4

I try to compare 2 array. 1 is from input::get and 1 is from query builder. 
Here is my code:

```
for ($k = 0; $k < $count; $k++) 
    { 
        $answer[] = Input::get('radio'.$k);
        $answerid[] = Input::get('input'.$k);

        $numberchoice[] = DB::table('numbers')->whereIn('questionid', array($answerid))->pluck('status');

        if ($answer == $numberchoice) 
        {
            $result[] = "1";
        }

        else
        {
            $result[] = "0";
        }
    }


    var_dump($answer); echo "<br>";
    var_dump($answerid); echo "<br>";
    var_dump($numberchoice); echo "<br>"; 

    $result = implode("%", $result);
    var_dump($result); echo "<br>"; 

    die();
```

i try to vardump every array to see what i got. I think the problem is at $numberchoice it keeps return me nothing. Although the $answer and $answerid is return correctly.

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "8" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "2" } 
array(5) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } 
string(9) "1%0%0%0%0"
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, `$answerid` is already an array. But when you call `->whereIn('questionid', array($answerid))` you are wrapping existing array into another one. The correct whereIn call would be `->whereIn('questionid', $answerid)`